# Can I list objects in my GCS Bucket by contentType? Or by suffix/file name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a GCS Storage bucket that is very large (tens of millions of objects). Over the past year or so there have been a handful of files that were uploaded with the incorrect MIME/content type, and those files were not processed correctly due to the incorrect type.

I would like to identify those files so they can be re-uploaded with the correct contentType so they can be processed correctly.

There are two ways that I think they could be identified without simply listing all objects in the bucket (due to cost of listing all objects):

1. List objects by content type. I know what the content type of the incorrect files will be, so if I could just perform something like `WHERE contentType` then I could easily get the files
2. Luckily, all the incorrect files will have the exact same file name. So if I could list files that have a "suffix" (as opposed to the supported prefix query) then I could get all those files.

Anyone have any ideas? If neither of these solutions are supported I guess I will have to list all the files in the bucket and spend hundreds of dollars.

Comment: Have you checked [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#wildcard-characters)? You can make make use of `**` wildcard characters to list the objects having a common suffix with `gsutil`.

Comment: Yes I had already tried the wildcards, but it doesn't seem to work since the files are in different subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the wildcard characters (`*`/`**` ) to list all objects matching a common suffix as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames).

In your use case to update the metadata for all the objects having a common suffix you can run a simple gsutil command as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta) and it will update the Content-Type of the objects.

As you have many files you can use the `-m` option for parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing) update. So a sample command will look like the following -

`gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type:image/png" gs://bucket-name/**.txt`

where the command will set the Content-Type to image/png for all objects inside the bucket whose name ends with `.txt`.

Comment: I think this answer is close but I just can't get the wild cards to work since the files are in separate subdirectories. Do you know if there's a way to handle wildcards with a directory structure like that?

Comment: The wildcard ended up working for me, I just had to surround the path in quotes because I'm using zsh